# Unknown error (0x80041002) when starting process on ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, uri

I have a very basic ASP.NET (.NET 4) forms application. This application is designed to control some items on the server.

One of the things I do is launch URIs on the server using `Process.Start(uri);`. During development, on my dev PC, it launches the process/URI just fine and works great. But when I try to launch the URI on the server, I get this error:

> Unknown error (0x80041002)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unknown error
>   (0x80041002)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error (0x80041002)]
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfostartInfo) +773
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +123
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +49
>   ...

If I take the same URI that I'm trying to launch from my website and put it into the Run box on the server directly, the application starts without any problems.

My dev machine is Windows 8 and my web server is Windows Server 2008R2.

Comment: The error message sounds incredibly vauge and thus hard to solve. 

Heres a relevant link to people with the same problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32e36d4d-df1b-40ee-9cc5-ddd8700651c7/unhandled-win32-exception

Summary is compatability problems although one guy found it was due to yahoo toolbar?? 

I dont have a good guess otherwise but maybe try the settings for the build/release versions?

Comment: Have you seen this link [1]? It says this method throws Win32Exception when "An error occurred when opening the associated file" or "The sum of the length of the arguments and the length of the full path to the process exceeds 2080. The error message associated with this exception can be one of the following: "The data area passed to a system call is too small." or "Access is denied." [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @heringer Just tried it with a URI length of 60 characters, and it still didn't work. That was a good guess, though.

Comment: If your ASP.NET code is trying to Process.Start, then it may be that the service running your application pool does not have permission to execute the command/resource. Can you try executing the command using the same account that runs the application pool?

Comment: @atom.gregg I think you were right, I switched the web app's authentication to the correct user but missed the app pool. Switching the app pool caused the error to go away, but the URI doesn't launch in the desktop session (the `Process.Start()` doesn't fail but doesn't do anything). Any quick ideas on how I could get the process to start in the correct Windows session so that it launches the correct application tied to the URI?

Comment: @atom.gregg Either way, if you add this as an answer I can accept it, since that was the cause of the error (regardless of if you figure out my URI problem). I can always ask another question since that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the user or service that is running the application pool has permission to execute the command(s) you need. It could simply be a permission problem.

I wouldn't expect anything to occur in the UI session if you are logged onto the machine at the same time though. The user running the service is only a process and is run and monitored by IIS.

You should see the process starting and ending if you open the task manager and check the option to show all processes for all users. This would be similar to running a database job and expecting to see the SSIS package open/run etc.

Comment: This ended up being the problem, though now the process simply starts and exits (the application does not detect that the URI was launched, though, which is different than if you enter the URI into the Run box). That is a separate issue, though, and warrants a separate question. Thanks!